# How to not include data in a text file if it is already in there

Tags: c#

I want to add data into a text file based on a specific output, it will read an XML file and write a certain line to a text file. If the data is already written into the text file, i dont want to write it again.

Code:

```
public void output(string folder)
{
    string S = "Data" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".xml";
    //Trades.Save(S);
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, S);
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    XDocument f = new XDocument(Trades);

    f.Save(path);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"H:\Test" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") + ".txt", true))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("CertainData"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
                if (File.ReadAllLines(path).Any(x => x.Equals(line)))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    string[] tradeRefLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                    File.WriteAllLines(path, tradeRefLines); ;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it will still write the line even if the data is exactly the same elsewhere. I don't want duplicate lines

Any advice?

*CLARIFICATION UPDATE*

The "CertainData" is a reference number

I have a bunch of files that has data in it and the piece i want to seperate and put into a text file is "CertainData" field, which will have a reference number

Sometimes the files i get sent will have the same formatted information inside it with the "CertainData" appearing in their for reference

When i run this programme, if the text file i have already contains the "CertainData" reference number inside it, i dont want it to be written

If you need anymore clarification let me know and i will update the post

Comment: You mean you don't want to write duplicate lines into a file?

Comment: If you must check if it exists *in all the document* and not on each line, then use ReadAllText, it will return only one string and then the Contains will give you the result you expect

Comment: @kkaosninja yes thats what im after, sorry if i wasnt clear enough

Comment: Why you are writing the same thing many time in the same path? Its too much confusing, what you are asking to correct and what your really want to do.

Comment: @sumngh For testing purposes, that is not the issue

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this: read all lines, filter out those containing a keyword and write it to a new file.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
var filteredLines = lines.Where(!line.Contains("CertainData"));
File.WriteAllLines(path, filteredLines);
```

If you also want to remove duplicate lines, you can add a distinct like this:

```
filteredLines = filteredLines.Distinct();
```

Comment: Great answer! unfortunately the data that is being added in the "CertainData" area is something which will be using unique identifiers.

Comment: What do you mean with unique identifiers? Can you explain in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use `Distinct` before `for` loop. This will filter your lines before write in file.

Try something like this

```
string[] lines = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "a" };

string[] filterLines = lines.Distinct().ToArray<string>();
```